# How to create a boolean mask inside a function, using time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter, stock

I have a simple function:

```
from numba import njit

# @njit
def my_logic_nb(close, open_, time):
    # create a numpy array that's the same shape as our close, setting each element to False
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)

    # loop through our closes
    for i in range(close.shape[0]):
        # whenever we close below the open (a red bar), then set our out to True
        if close[i] < open_[i]:
            out[i] = True
    
    print(out)
    return out
```

As the comments explain, this returns 1 dim array numpy array of the same shape as my close series, only returning True if my condition is met:

```
[False False False  True False False False False False False False False
 False False  True False False False  True False False  True False False
 False False False False False  True False False False False False False
  True False False False  True  True False False False False False  True
  True False False  True  True False False False  True  True  True False
 False False  True False False False False False  True False False False
 False False False False False False False False  True False False False
 False False False False False  True  True False False  True  True  True
  True  True False  True False False  True  True  True  True  True  True
 False False  True False False False False False False False  True False
  True  True  True  True False False False False False  True False  True
  True False False False False False  True False False  True False False
 False False  True False False  True False  True False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
  True  True  True  True  True  True False False False False False False
 False False False False  True False False False False False False False
 False False False  True False False False  True  True False  True False
  True  True  True False False False  True  True False False False False
  True False False False False False  True  True False False False False
 False False  True  True False  True False  True  True False  True False
  True False  True False  True False False  True  True False  True False
 False False False False False  True False  True False  True False False
 False False  True  True False False False False  True False  True False
 False False  True False False False False  True False False False False
 False False False False False False  True  True False False False  True
 False  True False False  True False False False False False  True False
 False  True False False  True  True  True  True False False False  True
  True False  True  True  True False False False False  True  True False
  True False False False  True False False  True  True  True False  True
  True False  True False False  True False False False  True False  True
 False False False False  True  True False  True False False False False
 False False  True  True False  True False  True  True  True False False
  True False False False False False False False  True  True False  True
 False False False  True  True False  True False  True False False False
  True False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False  True False False False False False False False False False
 False  True False False  True False  True False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
  True False False False  True False  True False False False False False
 False  True False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False  True  True False False False  True False False False
 False False  True False False False False False  True False False False
 False False  True False False False  True False False False False False
  True  True False False  True  True False False False False  True False
 False  True False False False False False False False False False False
  True  True False False False  True False  True False False False  True
  True  True False False False  True False False False False False  True
  True False  True False False False False  True  True False False  True
 False  True False False False  True  True False False False False False
 False False False False False False  True  True False  True  True False
  True False False False False  True False False False False  True  True
 False False False False  True False  True False False False False False
 False False False False False  True  True False False  True  True False
 False False False False False False False False False  True False  True
 False False False False False False False False  True  True False  True
 False False False False False  True False False False False False False
 False  True False False  True False False  True False False False False
 False False  True False False False False  True False False  True  True
 False False  True False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False  True
  True False False False  True False False False False False False False
  True False False False False  True  True False  True  True  True  True
 False False False  True False False  True  True False False  True  True
  True False False False False False False  True  True  True False False
  True  True False False  True False False False False False False  True
 False False False False False False False  True  True  True False False
  True  True False False False  True False  True  True False False False
 False False False False False False  True  True False False  True False
 False False False False False False False False False False False  True
  True False False False False False False False False False  True False
  True False  True  True False False False False False False False False
 False  True  True  True False False False False False  True False False
  True  True  True False  True  True  True False  True False False False
  True  True  True False  True  True  True False  True False  True False
  True  True  True  True False  True False  True  True False  True  True
  True False  True  True False  True  True False  True  True False False
 False  True  True  True  True False  True False False False False  True
 False  True  True  True  True False False  True  True  True False False
  True False False False  True  True False False  True  True False False
  True  True False  True  True  True False  True  True  True  True False
 False False False  True False False False False False  True False False
  True  True  True False False False  True False False False  True  True
  True  True  True False False  True  True False False False False False
 False False  True False False False False  True  True  True False  True
 False  True False False  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True
 False  True  True False False  True  True False  True  True False  True
  True False False  True False  True False  True  True False  True  True
 False False  True  True  True False  True False  True False  True False
 False False  True False  True False  True False False  True False False
 False False False  True False False  True False False False False  True
 False  True False  True  True  True False  True  True False  True  True
 False False False False  True  True  True False False False False  True
 False False False  True False  True False False False False  True  True
 False  True False  True  True  True  True  True  True False False False
 False  True False  True  True False False False  True False False False
  True  True  True False False False False False  True False False False
 False False False False  True  True False False  True  True  True False
 False  True  True  True False False  True  True False False False False
 False  True False  True False False  True False  True  True False False
 False False False False False False False False  True False  True False
 False False  True  True False False  True False False False  True False
 False False False False  True False  True False False False  True  True
  True False False False False False False False False False False  True
  True False False False False False  True  True  True  True False False
  True  True  True False  True False  True  True  True  True False False
 False False  True False False False False False  True  True False  True
 False False False False False False False  True False False False False
 False  True False False  True False False False  True False False False
 False False False False False  True False False False False False  True
 False False False False  True False False False  True  True False False
 False False False False False False False False False  True False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False  True False False  True False
 False False False False False  True False False  True False False False
 False]
```

What I want to be able to do is set my condition using times, so that any time falling outside of my condition will be set to False, e.g something like:

```
from numba import njit

# @njit
def my_logic_nb(close, open_, time):
    # create a numpy array that's the same shape as our close, setting each element to False
    out = np.full(close.shape, False)

    # loop through our closes
    for i in range(close.shape[0]):
        # only enter trades between 4am and 6am
        if time[i].between(time(4, 0), time(6, 0)):
            out[i] = True
    
    print(out)
    return out
```

In that psdeu code, my array would always be False outside the hours between 4 and 6am. How do I achieve this?

The type of `time` series:

```
datetime
2021-09-09 04:22:00    04:22:00
2021-09-09 07:18:00    07:18:00
2021-09-09 07:45:00    07:45:00
2021-09-09 08:00:00    08:00:00
2021-09-09 08:19:00    08:19:00
                         ...   
2021-09-10 19:53:00    19:53:00
2021-09-10 19:55:00    19:55:00
2021-09-10 19:56:00    19:56:00
2021-09-10 19:58:00    19:58:00
2021-09-10 19:59:00    19:59:00
Name: time, Length: 1369, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I've tried (as suggested by Michael):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = pd.date_range("2021-09-09 04:22:00", "2021-09-10 19:59:00", freq="5min")
print(time.shape)
from IPython.display import display
time = pd.Series(time, time)

out = np.full(time.shape, False)

# loop through our closes
for i in range(time.shape[0]):
    # only enter trades between 4am and 6am
    if (time[i].hour > 4) & (time[i].hour < 6):
        out[i] = True
    print(out[i])
    print(time[i])
```

Which gives me:

```
(476,)
False
2021-09-09 04:22:00
False
2021-09-09 04:27:00
False
2021-09-09 04:32:00
False
2021-09-09 04:37:00
False
2021-09-09 04:42:00
False
2021-09-09 04:47:00
False
2021-09-09 04:52:00
False
2021-09-09 04:57:00
True
2021-09-09 05:02:00
True
2021-09-09 05:07:00
True
2021-09-09 05:12:00
True
2021-09-09 05:17:00
True
2021-09-09 05:22:00
True
2021-09-09 05:27:00
True
2021-09-09 05:32:00
True
2021-09-09 05:37:00
True
2021-09-09 05:42:00
True
2021-09-09 05:47:00
True
2021-09-09 05:52:00
True
2021-09-09 05:57:00
False
2021-09-09 06:02:00
False
2021-09-09 06:07:00
False
2021-09-09 06:12:00
False
2021-09-09 06:17:00
False
2021-09-09 06:22:00
False
2021-09-09 06:27:00
False
2021-09-09 06:32:00
False
2021-09-09 06:37:00
False
2021-09-09 06:42:00
False
2021-09-09 06:47:00
False
2021-09-09 06:52:00
False
2021-09-09 06:57:00
False
2021-09-09 07:02:00
False
2021-09-09 07:07:00
False
2021-09-09 07:12:00
False
2021-09-09 07:17:00
False
2021-09-09 07:22:00
False
2021-09-09 07:27:00
False
2021-09-09 07:32:00
False
2021-09-09 07:37:00
False
2021-09-09 07:42:00
False
2021-09-09 07:47:00
False
2021-09-09 07:52:00
False
2021-09-09 07:57:00
False
2021-09-09 08:02:00
False
2021-09-09 08:07:00
False
2021-09-09 08:12:00
False
2021-09-09 08:17:00
False
2021-09-09 08:22:00
False
2021-09-09 08:27:00
False
2021-09-09 08:32:00
False
2021-09-09 08:37:00
False
2021-09-09 08:42:00
False
2021-09-09 08:47:00
False
2021-09-09 08:52:00
False
2021-09-09 08:57:00
False
2021-09-09 09:02:00
False
2021-09-09 09:07:00
False
2021-09-09 09:12:00
False
2021-09-09 09:17:00
False
2021-09-09 09:22:00
False
2021-09-09 09:27:00
False
2021-09-09 09:32:00
False
2021-09-09 09:37:00
False
2021-09-09 09:42:00
False
2021-09-09 09:47:00
False
2021-09-09 09:52:00
False
2021-09-09 09:57:00
False
2021-09-09 10:02:00
False
2021-09-09 10:07:00
False
2021-09-09 10:12:00
False
2021-09-09 10:17:00
False
2021-09-09 10:22:00
False
2021-09-09 10:27:00
False
2021-09-09 10:32:00
False
2021-09-09 10:37:00
False
2021-09-09 10:42:00
False
2021-09-09 10:47:00
False
2021-09-09 10:52:00
False
2021-09-09 10:57:00
False
2021-09-09 11:02:00
False
2021-09-09 11:07:00
False
2021-09-09 11:12:00
False
2021-09-09 11:17:00
False
2021-09-09 11:22:00
False
2021-09-09 11:27:00
False
2021-09-09 11:32:00
False
2021-09-09 11:37:00
False
2021-09-09 11:42:00
False
2021-09-09 11:47:00
False
2021-09-09 11:52:00
False
2021-09-09 11:57:00
False
2021-09-09 12:02:00
False
2021-09-09 12:07:00
False
2021-09-09 12:12:00
False
2021-09-09 12:17:00
False
2021-09-09 12:22:00
False
2021-09-09 12:27:00
False
2021-09-09 12:32:00
False
2021-09-09 12:37:00
False
2021-09-09 12:42:00
False
2021-09-09 12:47:00
False
2021-09-09 12:52:00
False
2021-09-09 12:57:00
False
2021-09-09 13:02:00
False
2021-09-09 13:07:00
False
2021-09-09 13:12:00
False
2021-09-09 13:17:00
False
2021-09-09 13:22:00
False
2021-09-09 13:27:00
False
2021-09-09 13:32:00
False
2021-09-09 13:37:00
False
2021-09-09 13:42:00
False
2021-09-09 13:47:00
False
2021-09-09 13:52:00
False
2021-09-09 13:57:00
False
2021-09-09 14:02:00
False
2021-09-09 14:07:00
False
2021-09-09 14:12:00
False
2021-09-09 14:17:00
False
2021-09-09 14:22:00
False
2021-09-09 14:27:00
False
2021-09-09 14:32:00
False
2021-09-09 14:37:00
False
2021-09-09 14:42:00
False
2021-09-09 14:47:00
False
2021-09-09 14:52:00
False
2021-09-09 14:57:00
False
2021-09-09 15:02:00
False
2021-09-09 15:07:00
False
2021-09-09 15:12:00
False
2021-09-09 15:17:00
False
2021-09-09 15:22:00
False
2021-09-09 15:27:00
False
2021-09-09 15:32:00
False
2021-09-09 15:37:00
False
2021-09-09 15:42:00
False
2021-09-09 15:47:00
False
2021-09-09 15:52:00
False
2021-09-09 15:57:00
False
2021-09-09 16:02:00
False
2021-09-09 16:07:00
False
2021-09-09 16:12:00
False
2021-09-09 16:17:00
False
2021-09-09 16:22:00
False
2021-09-09 16:27:00
False
2021-09-09 16:32:00
False
2021-09-09 16:37:00
False
2021-09-09 16:42:00
False
2021-09-09 16:47:00
False
2021-09-09 16:52:00
False
2021-09-09 16:57:00
False
2021-09-09 17:02:00
False
2021-09-09 17:07:00
False
2021-09-09 17:12:00
False
2021-09-09 17:17:00
False
2021-09-09 17:22:00
False
2021-09-09 17:27:00
False
2021-09-09 17:32:00
False
2021-09-09 17:37:00
False
2021-09-09 17:42:00
False
2021-09-09 17:47:00
False
2021-09-09 17:52:00
False
2021-09-09 17:57:00
False
2021-09-09 18:02:00
False
2021-09-09 18:07:00
False
2021-09-09 18:12:00
False
2021-09-09 18:17:00
False
2021-09-09 18:22:00
False
2021-09-09 18:27:00
False
2021-09-09 18:32:00
False
2021-09-09 18:37:00
False
2021-09-09 18:42:00
False
2021-09-09 18:47:00
False
2021-09-09 18:52:00
False
2021-09-09 18:57:00
False
2021-09-09 19:02:00
False
2021-09-09 19:07:00
False
2021-09-09 19:12:00
False
2021-09-09 19:17:00
False
2021-09-09 19:22:00
False
2021-09-09 19:27:00
False
2021-09-09 19:32:00
False
2021-09-09 19:37:00
False
2021-09-09 19:42:00
False
2021-09-09 19:47:00
False
2021-09-09 19:52:00
False
2021-09-09 19:57:00
False
2021-09-09 20:02:00
False
2021-09-09 20:07:00
False
2021-09-09 20:12:00
False
2021-09-09 20:17:00
False
2021-09-09 20:22:00
False
2021-09-09 20:27:00
False
2021-09-09 20:32:00
False
2021-09-09 20:37:00
False
2021-09-09 20:42:00
False
2021-09-09 20:47:00
False
2021-09-09 20:52:00
False
2021-09-09 20:57:00
False
2021-09-09 21:02:00
False
2021-09-09 21:07:00
False
2021-09-09 21:12:00
False
2021-09-09 21:17:00
False
2021-09-09 21:22:00
False
2021-09-09 21:27:00
False
2021-09-09 21:32:00
False
2021-09-09 21:37:00
False
2021-09-09 21:42:00
False
2021-09-09 21:47:00
False
2021-09-09 21:52:00
False
2021-09-09 21:57:00
False
2021-09-09 22:02:00
False
2021-09-09 22:07:00
False
2021-09-09 22:12:00
False
2021-09-09 22:17:00
False
2021-09-09 22:22:00
False
2021-09-09 22:27:00
False
2021-09-09 22:32:00
False
2021-09-09 22:37:00
False
2021-09-09 22:42:00
False
2021-09-09 22:47:00
False
2021-09-09 22:52:00
False
2021-09-09 22:57:00
False
2021-09-09 23:02:00
False
2021-09-09 23:07:00
False
2021-09-09 23:12:00
False
2021-09-09 23:17:00
False
2021-09-09 23:22:00
False
2021-09-09 23:27:00
False
2021-09-09 23:32:00
False
2021-09-09 23:37:00
False
2021-09-09 23:42:00
False
2021-09-09 23:47:00
False
2021-09-09 23:52:00
False
2021-09-09 23:57:00
False
2021-09-10 00:02:00
False
2021-09-10 00:07:00
False
2021-09-10 00:12:00
False
2021-09-10 00:17:00
False
2021-09-10 00:22:00
False
2021-09-10 00:27:00
False
2021-09-10 00:32:00
False
2021-09-10 00:37:00
False
2021-09-10 00:42:00
False
2021-09-10 00:47:00
False
2021-09-10 00:52:00
False
2021-09-10 00:57:00
False
2021-09-10 01:02:00
False
2021-09-10 01:07:00
False
2021-09-10 01:12:00
False
2021-09-10 01:17:00
False
2021-09-10 01:22:00
False
2021-09-10 01:27:00
False
2021-09-10 01:32:00
False
2021-09-10 01:37:00
False
2021-09-10 01:42:00
False
2021-09-10 01:47:00
False
2021-09-10 01:52:00
False
2021-09-10 01:57:00
False
2021-09-10 02:02:00
False
2021-09-10 02:07:00
False
2021-09-10 02:12:00
False
2021-09-10 02:17:00
False
2021-09-10 02:22:00
False
2021-09-10 02:27:00
False
2021-09-10 02:32:00
False
2021-09-10 02:37:00
False
2021-09-10 02:42:00
False
2021-09-10 02:47:00
False
2021-09-10 02:52:00
False
2021-09-10 02:57:00
False
2021-09-10 03:02:00
False
2021-09-10 03:07:00
False
2021-09-10 03:12:00
False
2021-09-10 03:17:00
False
2021-09-10 03:22:00
False
2021-09-10 03:27:00
False
2021-09-10 03:32:00
False
2021-09-10 03:37:00
False
2021-09-10 03:42:00
False
2021-09-10 03:47:00
False
2021-09-10 03:52:00
False
2021-09-10 03:57:00
False
2021-09-10 04:02:00
False
2021-09-10 04:07:00
False
2021-09-10 04:12:00
False
2021-09-10 04:17:00
False
2021-09-10 04:22:00
False
2021-09-10 04:27:00
False
2021-09-10 04:32:00
False
2021-09-10 04:37:00
False
2021-09-10 04:42:00
False
2021-09-10 04:47:00
False
2021-09-10 04:52:00
False
2021-09-10 04:57:00
True
2021-09-10 05:02:00
True
2021-09-10 05:07:00
True
2021-09-10 05:12:00
True
2021-09-10 05:17:00
True
2021-09-10 05:22:00
True
2021-09-10 05:27:00
True
2021-09-10 05:32:00
True
2021-09-10 05:37:00
True
2021-09-10 05:42:00
True
2021-09-10 05:47:00
True
2021-09-10 05:52:00
True
2021-09-10 05:57:00
False
2021-09-10 06:02:00
False
2021-09-10 06:07:00
False
2021-09-10 06:12:00
False
2021-09-10 06:17:00
False
2021-09-10 06:22:00
False
2021-09-10 06:27:00
False
2021-09-10 06:32:00
False
2021-09-10 06:37:00
False
2021-09-10 06:42:00
False
2021-09-10 06:47:00
False
2021-09-10 06:52:00
False
2021-09-10 06:57:00
False
2021-09-10 07:02:00
False
2021-09-10 07:07:00
False
2021-09-10 07:12:00
False
2021-09-10 07:17:00
False
2021-09-10 07:22:00
False
2021-09-10 07:27:00
False
2021-09-10 07:32:00
False
2021-09-10 07:37:00
False
2021-09-10 07:42:00
False
2021-09-10 07:47:00
False
2021-09-10 07:52:00
False
2021-09-10 07:57:00
False
2021-09-10 08:02:00
False
2021-09-10 08:07:00
False
2021-09-10 08:12:00
False
2021-09-10 08:17:00
False
2021-09-10 08:22:00
False
2021-09-10 08:27:00
False
2021-09-10 08:32:00
False
2021-09-10 08:37:00
False
2021-09-10 08:42:00
False
2021-09-10 08:47:00
False
2021-09-10 08:52:00
False
2021-09-10 08:57:00
False
2021-09-10 09:02:00
False
2021-09-10 09:07:00
False
2021-09-10 09:12:00
False
2021-09-10 09:17:00
False
2021-09-10 09:22:00
False
2021-09-10 09:27:00
False
2021-09-10 09:32:00
False
2021-09-10 09:37:00
False
2021-09-10 09:42:00
False
2021-09-10 09:47:00
False
2021-09-10 09:52:00
False
2021-09-10 09:57:00
False
2021-09-10 10:02:00
False
2021-09-10 10:07:00
False
2021-09-10 10:12:00
False
2021-09-10 10:17:00
False
2021-09-10 10:22:00
False
2021-09-10 10:27:00
False
2021-09-10 10:32:00
False
2021-09-10 10:37:00
False
2021-09-10 10:42:00
False
2021-09-10 10:47:00
False
2021-09-10 10:52:00
False
2021-09-10 10:57:00
False
2021-09-10 11:02:00
False
2021-09-10 11:07:00
False
2021-09-10 11:12:00
False
2021-09-10 11:17:00
False
2021-09-10 11:22:00
False
2021-09-10 11:27:00
False
2021-09-10 11:32:00
False
2021-09-10 11:37:00
False
2021-09-10 11:42:00
False
2021-09-10 11:47:00
False
2021-09-10 11:52:00
False
2021-09-10 11:57:00
False
2021-09-10 12:02:00
False
2021-09-10 12:07:00
False
2021-09-10 12:12:00
False
2021-09-10 12:17:00
False
2021-09-10 12:22:00
False
2021-09-10 12:27:00
False
2021-09-10 12:32:00
False
2021-09-10 12:37:00
False
2021-09-10 12:42:00
False
2021-09-10 12:47:00
False
2021-09-10 12:52:00
False
2021-09-10 12:57:00
False
2021-09-10 13:02:00
False
2021-09-10 13:07:00
False
2021-09-10 13:12:00
False
2021-09-10 13:17:00
False
2021-09-10 13:22:00
False
2021-09-10 13:27:00
False
2021-09-10 13:32:00
False
2021-09-10 13:37:00
False
2021-09-10 13:42:00
False
2021-09-10 13:47:00
False
2021-09-10 13:52:00
False
2021-09-10 13:57:00
False
2021-09-10 14:02:00
False
2021-09-10 14:07:00
False
2021-09-10 14:12:00
False
2021-09-10 14:17:00
False
2021-09-10 14:22:00
False
2021-09-10 14:27:00
False
2021-09-10 14:32:00
False
2021-09-10 14:37:00
False
2021-09-10 14:42:00
False
2021-09-10 14:47:00
False
2021-09-10 14:52:00
False
2021-09-10 14:57:00
False
2021-09-10 15:02:00
False
2021-09-10 15:07:00
False
2021-09-10 15:12:00
False
2021-09-10 15:17:00
False
2021-09-10 15:22:00
False
2021-09-10 15:27:00
False
2021-09-10 15:32:00
False
2021-09-10 15:37:00
False
2021-09-10 15:42:00
False
2021-09-10 15:47:00
False
2021-09-10 15:52:00
False
2021-09-10 15:57:00
False
2021-09-10 16:02:00
False
2021-09-10 16:07:00
False
2021-09-10 16:12:00
False
2021-09-10 16:17:00
False
2021-09-10 16:22:00
False
2021-09-10 16:27:00
False
2021-09-10 16:32:00
False
2021-09-10 16:37:00
False
2021-09-10 16:42:00
False
2021-09-10 16:47:00
False
2021-09-10 16:52:00
False
2021-09-10 16:57:00
False
2021-09-10 17:02:00
False
2021-09-10 17:07:00
False
2021-09-10 17:12:00
False
2021-09-10 17:17:00
False
2021-09-10 17:22:00
False
2021-09-10 17:27:00
False
2021-09-10 17:32:00
False
2021-09-10 17:37:00
False
2021-09-10 17:42:00
False
2021-09-10 17:47:00
False
2021-09-10 17:52:00
False
2021-09-10 17:57:00
False
2021-09-10 18:02:00
False
2021-09-10 18:07:00
False
2021-09-10 18:12:00
False
2021-09-10 18:17:00
False
2021-09-10 18:22:00
False
2021-09-10 18:27:00
False
2021-09-10 18:32:00
False
2021-09-10 18:37:00
False
2021-09-10 18:42:00
False
2021-09-10 18:47:00
False
2021-09-10 18:52:00
False
2021-09-10 18:57:00
False
2021-09-10 19:02:00
False
2021-09-10 19:07:00
False
2021-09-10 19:12:00
False
2021-09-10 19:17:00
False
2021-09-10 19:22:00
False
2021-09-10 19:27:00
False
2021-09-10 19:32:00
False
2021-09-10 19:37:00
False
2021-09-10 19:42:00
False
2021-09-10 19:47:00
False
2021-09-10 19:52:00
False
2021-09-10 19:57:00
```

Comment: does `(time.dt.hour > 4) & (time.dt.hour < 6)` work?

Comment: Hey @MichaelDelgado thanks for your reply, sadly it did not work. I have updated the OP with the code I tried - is that the sort of thing you meant?

Comment: I mean with the whole array - see my answer

Comment: if you have to do this, you should be able to just reference the hour attribute, not `.dt.hour`

Comment: Almost @MichaelDelgado but not quite. See my updated post - any ideas why it would be printing like that? P.s thank you once again

Comment: Sorted it, thank you @MichaelDelgado

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through all elements, use pandas' builtin [datetime accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors). Specifically, [`Series.dt.hour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```py
In [17]: time = pd.date_range("2021-09-09 04:22:00", "2021-09-10 19:59:00", freq="5min")

In [18]: time = pd.Series(time, time)

In [19]: (time.dt.hour > 4) & (time.dt.hour < 6)
Out[19]:
2021-09-09 04:22:00    False
2021-09-09 04:27:00    False
2021-09-09 04:32:00    False
2021-09-09 04:37:00    False
2021-09-09 04:42:00    False
                       ...
2021-09-10 19:37:00    False
2021-09-10 19:42:00    False
2021-09-10 19:47:00    False
2021-09-10 19:52:00    False
2021-09-10 19:57:00    False
Freq: 5T, Length: 476, dtype: bool

In [20]: time[(time.dt.hour > 4) & (time.dt.hour < 6)]
Out[20]:
2021-09-09 05:02:00   2021-09-09 05:02:00
2021-09-09 05:07:00   2021-09-09 05:07:00
2021-09-09 05:12:00   2021-09-09 05:12:00
2021-09-09 05:17:00   2021-09-09 05:17:00
2021-09-09 05:22:00   2021-09-09 05:22:00
2021-09-09 05:27:00   2021-09-09 05:27:00
2021-09-09 05:32:00   2021-09-09 05:32:00
2021-09-09 05:37:00   2021-09-09 05:37:00
2021-09-09 05:42:00   2021-09-09 05:42:00
2021-09-09 05:47:00   2021-09-09 05:47:00
2021-09-09 05:52:00   2021-09-09 05:52:00
2021-09-09 05:57:00   2021-09-09 05:57:00
2021-09-10 05:02:00   2021-09-10 05:02:00
2021-09-10 05:07:00   2021-09-10 05:07:00
2021-09-10 05:12:00   2021-09-10 05:12:00
2021-09-10 05:17:00   2021-09-10 05:17:00
2021-09-10 05:22:00   2021-09-10 05:22:00
2021-09-10 05:27:00   2021-09-10 05:27:00
2021-09-10 05:32:00   2021-09-10 05:32:00
2021-09-10 05:37:00   2021-09-10 05:37:00
2021-09-10 05:42:00   2021-09-10 05:42:00
2021-09-10 05:47:00   2021-09-10 05:47:00
2021-09-10 05:52:00   2021-09-10 05:52:00
2021-09-10 05:57:00   2021-09-10 05:57:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

See the guide to [date & time functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-date-components) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I need to loop through the elements as I will need to include other logic there besides limiting of the time period

Comment: you can filter on other things with &, as I've done here. it's never a good idea to loop over every element of a dataframe.